# Cassandra + data insertion + set<FROZEN<map<text,text>>>

Tags: json, cassandra, cql3

My column family structure is:

```
create table mykeyspc."test" (
id int PRIMARY KEY,
val set<frozen<map<text,text>>>
);
```

when I am inserting data through CQL shell

```
insert into "test" JSON '{"id":1,"val":{"ab","bc"}}';
Error: INVALIDREQUEST: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Counld not decode JSon string as 
map:org.codehaus.jackson.jsonParseException: Unexpected character{'{'{ code 123})
```

or

```
insert into "test" (id,val) values (1,{{'ab','bc'},{'sdf','name'}});
Error: INVALIDREQUEST: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="INVALID SET LITERAL FOR
VAL:value{'a','b'} is not of type frozen<map<text,text>>"
```

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?  I only ask, because the question is tagged "cassandra-2.0," but defining a table with a `set<frozen<map<...` is only valid in 2.1+.

Comment: My guess is 2.2+ since the server attempts to parse the JSON in the first statement.

Comment: Good call.  Thanks @Adam !

Comment: thanks Aaron and Adam, problem resolved.. i am using 2.1 version only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second example, try separating the map key/values with colons `:` instead of commas.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO mapOfSet (id,val) 
                             VALUES (1,{{'ab':'bc'},{'sdf':'name'}});
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm mapofset WHERE id=1;

 id | val
----+---------------------------------
  1 | {{'ab': 'bc'}, {'sdf': 'name'}}

(1 rows)
```